# Springmongo legacy geospatial query vs GeoJSON

Tags: mongodb, geospatial, geojson, spring-mongo

I am using springmongo 1.7.2 with mongodb 2.6.0

My collection object looks like this in JSON:

```
{
    "childObject1" : {

        "description" : "Lorem ipsum",

        childObject2" : {
            "someField" : "someValue",
            "loc" : [-82.123123, 28.123123123]
        }
    }
}
```

To construct a text query along with geospatial data I use the following, which is working fine:

```
TextCriteria textCriteria = TextCriteria.forDefaultLanguage().matchingAny(searchTerms); 

Point point = new Point(long, lat);
Distance d = new Distance(radius, Metrics.MILES);
Circle circle = new Circle(point, radius/69.172);
Criteria gloablCriteria = Criteria.where("childObject1.childObject2.loc").within(circle);

Query q = new Query();
q = TextQuery.queryText(textCriteria);
q.addCriteria(globalCriteria);

List<MyObject> results = mongoOps.find(q, MyObject.class);
```

However, if I change the format of the loc object to GeoJSON (as below), then I can't get the query to work. The result list is empty with no error on the server console.

```
"loc" : {"type" : "Point", "coordinates":[-82.123123, 28.123123123]}
```

P.S. After changing the format of the loc attribute I dropped and recreated the geospatial index:

```
createIndex("{MyObject.childObject1.childObject2.loc":"2dsphere"})
```

Comment: Do you mean a "text search" ( `$text` ) query alongside a geospatial `$nearSphere`? I strongly doubt that you have any case where this is working. MongoDB does not allow the use of more than one "special" index at a time. Maybe you acutally did a "text" query with a `$geoWithin`, where the latter operator does not require an index.

Comment: My bad, with legacy format I use spring's "within" (not "withinSphere"). Made a mistake while copypasting the code. Will correct now

Comment: You also seem to be missing your "loc" field name in the "where". But read what I said earlier. No geospatial index can be used here alongside a text query. `$geoWithin` is valid, but it will not use an index. It just filters the results from the "text" query, so also consider you might really expect that to happen the other way around, Be aware that if your data is now in GeoJSON, then the distances reported and compared are also now in "kilometers" as that is the standard. Miles are bigger than kilometers, so your "circle" may not be reaching out far enough.

Comment: So, what I thought of as "working" before was not really working cause mongo was using either the text index or the geospatial, but not both? .. and there is no way to ask for _"records with such and such text within a given geo circle"_ ?

Comment: A `$geoWithin` will *"work"*, it's just that it may not be *"optimally"* doing what you think. In this case the "text" results will be made first and then filtered for the location lying "within". What cannot happen is the other way around, where you only search the words from locations within the required "radius". It' just means you are likely scanning more data that you likely want to. If you are not getting results now, it's likely the cause of the distances being considered in a different measurement. Check your parameters and "widen" the search.

Comment: I changed it to use kilometers like so: `Distance d = new Distance(radius, Metrics.KILOMETERS);` but can't make sense out of the returned results. For example with my test data I expect 2 records within 14 miles and 3 records within 25 miles. However, with kilometers I get no results up until 114 and get all three records with 115